# Clicking in IE using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I want to click on a button in IE (which probably is not actually a button) using VBA. The problem is that there is no ID or name in the source of the "button" I want to click on.

Here is the part of the source of the webpage (see link):

[Part of source (NEW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EApA.png)

I want to click on the part which has as text: "Informatie" in it. Im currently using the following code (just a part of it) in VBA. But when i excecute the code, nothing happens, not even an error message:

```
 Dim e
 Set e = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("BackgroundApp")(0).getElementsByTagName("Div")(7).getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
 e.Click
```

Comment: Expand that highlighted `DIV` tag and post the relevant source code.

Comment: It is the one that is expanded (the last DIV tag). Dont mind the row that is dark selected.

Comment: `Informatie` button ?

Comment: That <td which is expaned from that last div has the text "Informatie" in it. As you can see on the picutre.

Comment: I made a new picture with the selected part of the source I want to click on using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without actual page, so I replicate it and here is the tested code:

```
Dim IE as Object
Dim objCollection  As Object
Dim tdNode  As Object

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")

For Each tdNode In objCollection
    If InStr(1, tdNode.innerHTML, "Informatie", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' "Informatie" button is found
        tdNode.Click    ' click it
        Exit For
    End If
Next tdNode
```

Give it a try and report back.

Comment: Thank you for putting effort in my case! Unfortunately still nothing happened. I cant give you the actual page, because it is a internal web application on our own server.

Comment: Than talk to developers and ask them to assign proper tag to that button.